# Android UpdateManager issues - not all devices get the update information

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I am using Android UpdateManager to get information about my app update and perform auto update. 
I am calling below code in my MainActivity.onCreate. The problem is some of my devices get the update information and display the update activity, but some not. All the devices have Google Play Services installed. What may be the reason of UpdateManager not working consistently?

```
AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
    // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
    // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                // For a flexible update, use AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
                && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
            // Request the update.
            try {
                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE, this, REQUEST_CHECK_FOR_APP_UPDATE);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Logger.log(Logger.error, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnFailureListener(e -> {
        Logger.log(Logger.error, e.getMessage());
    });
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No. I haven't found.